# Creating Sinatra Extension That Depends On Another Sinatra Extension

Tags: ruby, dependency-injection, sinatra, modularity

I'm extracting functionality from a sinatra application into an extension. My extension module (`ExtensionBar`) depends on the existence of class-level dsl extensions created by another extension module (`ExtensionFoo`). Because of this, my extension dies when `require`d by my main app.

my_app.rb:

```
require "extension_foo"
require "extension_bar"    

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register ExtensionFoo
  register ExtensionBar
end
```

extension_foo.rb:

```
module ExtensionFoo
  def with_foo
    yield
  end
end
```

extension_bar.rb:

```
module ExtensionBar
  with_foo do
    "bar"
  end
end
```

My question: How can I most robustly and simply write an extension that depends on the registry of another extension? I'd like to avoid metaprogramming as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've given, ExtensionBar doesn't do anything to any app. You also need to register the dependent extension in the extension you wish to use in the app. The [instructions on writing modules](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html) gives a `before` block as the example for the LinkBlocker DSL, both of which would make your example more like this:

```
# extension_foo.rb

require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module ExtensionFoo
    def with_foo
      warn "Calling with_foo"
      s = yield
      warn "s = #{s}"
      s
    end
  end
  register ExtensionFoo
end


# extension_bar.rb

require 'sinatra/base'
require_relative 'extension_foo.rb'

module Sinatra
  module ExtensionBar
    before do
      warn "Calling with_foo in before"
      with_foo do
        "bar"
      end
    end
  end
  register ExtensionBar
end


# app.rb

require 'sinatra'
require_relative 'extension_bar.rb'

get "/" do
  with_foo do
    "blah"
  end.inspect
end
```

When I run this I don't get an error and I do see the warnings in my STDOUT, and the output is "blah".

```
Calling with_foo in before
Calling with_foo
    from /Volumes/RubyProjects/Test/extension_dependency/extension_foo.rb:6:in `with_foo'
s = bar
    from /Volumes/RubyProjects/Test/extension_dependency/extension_foo.rb:8:in `with_foo'
Calling with_foo
    from /Volumes/RubyProjects/Test/extension_dependency/extension_foo.rb:6:in `with_foo'
s = blah
    from /Volumes/RubyProjects/Test/extension_dependency/extension_foo.rb:8:in `with_foo'
```